Unexpected OpAmp output waveform
I am building a sawtooth waveform generator based on NE555:

In LTspice, I got a clear waveform:

In practice, the output signal has unexpected ripples like below:

What could be a reason for those ripples?

This seems to be the slew rate of the opamp...

Some components values are not well chosen.

What components are incorrect? I've tried a lot, but result still same

There are no scales on the waveforms at all

Unwanted ringing appears also when a non-experienced oscilloscope user has (for covenience) a long extra ground wire, maybe even the ground is taken to the oscilloscope with the other probe. There's a good reason why the wire of the probe ground clip is only about 10 centimeters long and even it is sometimes too long with fast pulses. If the 555 ouputs good not ringing rectangular pulses with the same oscilloscope GND constellation, the problem, of course, is elsewhere.

@oneprivate  True but not here. The ripple is triangular.   read my answer

@D.A.S. The questioner has accepted one of the answers while I sketched my comment. That comment is written without knowing any numbers of the case, so it was only a guess and let it be one. The rising ramp has visually looked as slow in some cases when I have met the too long ground wire oscilloscope usage error. I know well the possibility that a feedback loop can generate oscillations due the phase shift.

@oneprivate understood. His last plot  is a clear triangle decaying meaning the harmonics are due to wide band attenuation with poor phase margin and not LC fundamental resonance of a ground loop.  The accepted answer is correct but the simple advice will not work and thus wrong. read why in my answer

OK. I have red it. Can you emphasize some easy measuring trick which applied to an existing circuit makes a difference between ringing caused by the non-linear rate clipping (=limited opamp slew rate) and the ringing caused by the linear phase lag in the feedback loop?

The simple answer is that, when responding to a quick input change, the op amp is only marginally stable. The simple fix is probably a small capacitor across R8. This will slow down the response of the op amp, but one way of looking at the problem is that the op amp is trying to respond too quickly to a major input change.Try a 10 pf to 100 pf and see what happens.
The more complete answer is beyond my abilities in this space, but in general a (sometimes very small) feedback capacitor is a very good idea. It will compensate for various parasitic effects that you may encounter in actually building a circuit.

triangle decaying meaning the harmonics are due to wide band attenuation with poor phase margin and not slew rate gain. but you can attenuate slew rate as a compromise this way.   This accepted answer is correct but the simple advice will not work and thus wrong. read why in my answer. Use non-inverting input and  better OA.  Also try to specify the 3 tradeoffs

The problem is the rise time of the sawtooth approaches the slew rate limit of your chosen Op Amp. You have the wrong device to meet your expectations with a risetime < 50 ns.
The reason is shown by the Bode Phase margin and the small signal step response in the datasheet.  Any time there is ringing you have at least a 2nd order error in the response which may be improved using better devices or reducing your BW. Sometimes a discrete BJT design is needed to get more BW with current gain and low voltage gain.

ref
What is the solution?
Define specs for risetime, and overshoot thus phase margin.
Choose a simple design that meets this.
Can a video IC or Op Amp do this?  Or is it better with discrete?
Do you compromise rise time or overshoot or phase margin?
This is the tradeoff.
What is my 1 minute solution?  Ask GPT with suitable specs.
Lookup sheet. Bang. Use Non-Inverting input not inverting input.
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa847.pdf?ts=1735655178453&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FOPA847

I added two "little" 1 pF capacitors (wiring capacitance, schematic "incomplete" ?).
It seems that the ripples could be from these ...
Here is what I simulated with microcap v12.

Note that the frequency does not seem to be the same like OP diagrams.
